Title: Flutterwave API Integration: Facing 403 Forbidden Error with Provided Example Code
I am attempting to integrate Flutterwave's payment gateway into my website using their provided example code. The example code I am using looks like this.
<form>
  <div>
    Your order is ₦2,500
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="start-payment-button" onclick="makePayment()">Pay Now</button>
</form>
<script>
  function makePayment() {
    FlutterwaveCheckout({
      public_key: "confirmed correct public key",
      tx_ref: "txref-DI0NzMx13",
      amount: 250,
      currency: "NGN",
      payment_options: "card, banktransfer, ussd",
      meta: {
        source: "docs-inline-test",
        consumer_mac: "92a3-912ba-1192a",
      },
      customer: {
        email: "test@mailinator.com",
        phone_number: "08100000000",
        name: "Ayomide Jimi-Oni",
      },
      customizations: {
        title: "Flutterwave Developers",
        description: "Test Payment",
        logo: "https://checkout.flutterwave.com/assets/img/rave-logo.png",
      },
      callback: function (data){
        console.log("payment callback:", data);
      },
      onclose: function() {
        console.log("Payment cancelled!");
      }
    });
  }
</script>


However, when I try to run this code, I encounter a 403 Forbidden error. The error message looks like this:
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
</body>

I have confirmed that the public key in the code is correct. Could someone please assist me in resolving this issue? Thank you!


There documentation https://developer.flutterwave.com/docs/collecting-payments/inline
